# Octave installation after purging previous installation

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, software-uninstall, purge, octave

I installed the octave 4.0.3 version and for some reason the command window didn't show any text. I dont know why i decided to purge the installation and start all over thinking i messed up somewhere

These is the command I executed-

```
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove octave
```

But this gave me errors while reinstalling octave so i did this -

```
sudo dpkg --list | grep octave
sudo dpkg --remove liboctave3:amd64
sudo dpkg --remove octave
sudo dpkg --remove octave-common
sudo dpkg --remove octave-info
```

as these were the 4 that showed up in the list

after that i ran this again and purged the packages that showed up -

```
sudo dpkg --list | grep octave
sudo dpkg --purge liboctave3:amd64
sudo dpkg --purge octave-common
```

On running this -

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

I got an error saying my /usr/local/share/octave/packages did not exist
and so based on some forum reply i manually removed the entire octave folder both in my home path and the one in the /usr/local/share/octave/ path using

```
cd /usr/local/share/
sudo rm -r octave
```

upon getting more errors i did -

```
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

and now on running -

```
sudo apt-get build-dep octave
```

i get the following -

```
[sudo] password for lightweight-autonomy: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 6 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up octave (4.0.2-1ubuntu5~octave~trusty1) ...
warning: docstring file '/usr/local/share/octave/4.0.3/etc/built-in-docstrings' not found
error: feval: function 'gnuplot_binary' not found
error: called from
    /usr/local/lib/octave/4.0.3/oct/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/PKG_ADD at line 5 column 1
error: octave_base_value::convert_to_str_internal (): wrong type argument '<unknown type>'
error: called from
    /usr/local/lib/octave/4.0.3/oct/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/PKG_ADD at line 5 column 1
dpkg: error processing package octave (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
E: Failed to process build dependencies
```

Please help me as i need to install octave but can't find anything to help me.

Sorry for the long post but i thought i must provide a list of all the stupid things i did which led me to this. I'm new on this and i really wish there was a way to start over.
thanks.

Comment: Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

so I finally fixed the problem. I used the following -

```
sudo apt-get autoremove octave
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install libblas-dev liblapack-dev libpcre3-dev libarpack2-dev libcurl4-gnutls-dev epstool libfftw3-dev transfig libfltk1.3-dev libfontconfig1-dev libfreetype6-dev libgl2ps-dev libglpk-dev libreadline-dev gnuplot libgraphicsmagick++-dev libhdf5-serial-dev openjdk-7-jdk libsndfile1-dev llvm-dev lpr texinfo libgl1-mesa-dev libosmesa6-dev pstoedit portaudio19-dev libqhull-dev libqrupdate-dev libqscintilla2-dev libqt4-dev libqtcore4 libqtwebkit4 libqt4-network libqtgui4 libsuitesparse-dev libxft-dev zlib1g-dev
```

and then in the directory that I unzipped the tar file -

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

IMPORTANT: I had done these things before but without the sudo apt-get update/upgrade commands and it led to problems. so that's definitely an important step.